# Is telling white lie permitted in Islam?

Tags: practical-islam

> Which types of white lies are permitted? What about those little white
>   lies we often use in our daily life?

Example: I don't like gossiping, so whenever anyone like that call me or ask me to go outside, I always ignore by saying that I'll be a bit busy for those few days or I've to go right now etc.

This is the most said lie by me, because I really don't know how to deal with it, if I be straight forward, then they will be hurt. (truth often hurts)

Another lie I sometime say about nafal fast, whenever I do fast and meet people, I don't like to tell the truth that I am fasting, because they start commenting, that I feel like interfering too much.

> So, how should we deal with these type of lies which we use often to
>   ignore some unwanted behavior or not to hurt others?

Answer (score 1):

> liar is not one who **tries to bring reconciliation amongst people and speaks good (in order to avert dispute), or he conveys good**." (Sahih Muslim)
>
> The Prophet  sallallaahu  alayhi  wa  sallam ( may  Allaah exalt his mention ) said: "Ibraaheem  may  Allaah  exalt  his  mention never lied except in three cases, two for Allaah, **when he said [as an excuse when asked by his people to join them in celebration of their idols] "I am sick"**; and [when they came back and asked who broke their idols, he said] "Rather, it was the biggest among them who did that." And the third was about Saarah, and that was his saying: "When he asks you, say you are my sister, because you are my sister in Islam." (Sahih Muslim)

The above two Ahadith should insha allah clarify the issue for you.